# Регулярное выражение без учета регистра php

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Как собственно преобразовать регулярное выражение так, в данном коде обработчика изображения, чтобы при выборе файла с расширением .jPg, .pnG и т д, не прекращала работу функция и вообще принимало расширение картинке без учета регистра?

```
   ...

   if(preg_match('/[.](jpg)|(JPG)$/', $filename)) {
        $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($path_to_image_directory . $filename);
    } else if (preg_match('/[.](gif)|(GIF)$/', $filename)) {
        $im = imagecreatefromgif($path_to_image_directory . $filename);
    } else if (preg_match('/[.](png)|(PNG)$/', $filename)) {
        $im = imagecreatefrompng($path_to_image_directory . $filename);
    }

    ...
```

Comment: Открываем доку http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php  ищем (по Ctrl+F) слово регистр ... видим, что после закрывающей `/` надо добавить букву `i` итого `preg_match('/[.]jpg$/i', ...)`

Comment: @Mike Ох, сейчас проверю, но думаю все должно работать. Спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пробуйте например так https://regex101.com/r/Pd8Log/3
То есть конкретно для джпега

`#.+\.jpe?g#is`

гифа соответственно

`#.+\.gif#is`

Comment: То есть так? ...  preg_match('/.+\.jpe?g/is', ...)